# GCC makefile dependency generation path

Tags: gcc, makefile

I use the `-MM` flag in GCC to generate makefile dependencies for objects. The makefile briefly looks like this:

```
-include autodep
...
$(TARGET): build $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) -shared -o $@ $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) -MM $(SOURCES) > autodep
```

The sources are located the in folder `src`. However, the `autodep` file will contain the object targets without their relative path:

```
foo.o: src/foo.c src/foo.h
bar.o: src/bar.c src/bar.h src/baz.h
```

How should I turn them into this:

```
src/foo.o: src/foo.c src/foo.h
src/bar.o: src/bar.c src/bar.h src/baz.h
```

?

I tried using the `-MT` flag, but it seems to discard object targets altogether.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`-MT` sets the entire target name.  If you want a different target for each source, you need a different `-MT` argument for each source, which means multiple invocations of the compiler and a foreach loop:

```
$(TARGET): build $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) -shared -o $@ $(OBJECTS)
    rm autodep
    $(foreach SRC,$(SOURCES),$(CC) -MM -MT $(SRC:.c=.o) $(SRC) >> autodep;)
```

Alternately, you can use sed to massage the output

```
$(TARGET): build $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) -shared -o $@ $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) -MM $(SOURCES) | sed 's|^|src/|' > autodep
```

Easier still is to put the dependencies for each source file into it own .d file and use the `-MMD` flag to generate that when you compile the source file:

```
-include $(SOURCES:.c=.d)
CFLAGS += -MMD

$(TARGET): build $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) -shared -o $@ $(OBJECTS)
```

Comment: Thanks! I use the `foreach` loop, and the contents of `autodep` are correct now. But it doesn't actually seem to work. Using the example from the question, if I change `src/bar.h` and run `make` I just get `make: \`src/foo.o' is up to date`.

Comment: Solved it by putting the `-include` after `all:`.